# c++ : Help correcting endless loop while modifying c-string array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, c-strings

I have a homework assignment that involves creating a c-string array from user input, modifying the content of the array so every other letter is capitalized, and outputting the final result. My code is currently stuck in an endless loop. I'm struggling to understand exactly how to access the array and then modify it. (We just started working with arrays this week.) I have pasted my code below. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

const int j = 1024;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char letter;
    char lineArray[j];
    char modifyArray[j];

    cout << "Hello! Please type a letter, word, "  //user input prompt
    << "or phrase, followed by enter." << endl;

    cin.getline(lineArray, j);

    for(int i=0; i < 1024; i++)
    {
         letter = lineArray[i];

        while (letter != '\n')           //change and store letters
            {
                if (i%2 == 0)
                    letter = toupper(letter);
                else if(i%2 != 0)
                    letter = tolower(letter);
            }

        modifyArray[i] = letter;
    }

    cout << modifyArray[j];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not every line ends with '\n'. Calculate length of the string before iterating over it.

Comment: If the first letter is an `'A'`, then the `while` loop will be infinite because `'A' != '\n'`, and it doesn't matter if you change it to `'a'`, since `'a'` isn't equal to `'\n'` either. The outer loop should be `for(int i=0;lineArray[i]!='\0';i++)` and the `while` just needs to go away.

Comment: `while (letter != '\n')` - the only way out of here is to set letter to `'\n'` - which you never do... - also no need to say `else if (i%2 != 0)`, just say `else`.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code snippet

```
letter = lineArray[i];
while (letter != '\n')           //change and store letters
    {
        if (i%2 == 0)
            letter = toupper(letter);
        else if(i%2 != 0)
            letter = tolower(letter);
    }
```

You are looping based on `letter`, but inside the loop, it isn't changed in a way that it would ever change to `'\n'`.

Also, when using `getline`, the `'\n'` character (new-line symbol) doesn't get put to the string, so your comparison with `'\n'` is pointless. Instead, change your for loop to the following (and remove the while loop):

```
for(int i=0; i < strlen (lineArray) + 1; i++) // You need strlen + 1, because otherwise string terminating '\0' character wouldn't be copied over.
```

That way, you would loop for exactly the length of a string (assuming in never has more than 1024 characters.

Also, you should print the array like this:

```
cout << modifyArray;
```

Because in your code, you are printing the first character that is out of bounds of your array.

Comment: Thank you so much! My code works perfectly now. I really appreciate your help.